# itext7 c# adding image as a header overlaps text

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext7

I am new to iText7, and using the Java examples, I am able to convert HTML to a pdf, and to add a header and footer. The problem is when I create a header which is an image, the text on the page overlaps it. Can you help me figure out how to get the text on the page to appear *under* the header? Thank you so much! Here is my ImageHeader class:

```
class ImageHeader: IEventHandler  {

String imagePath ;//{ get; set; }

public ImageHeader(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath=imagePath;
}    

//public void HandleEvent(Event event) {
public void HandleEvent(Event the_event) {

    // Retrieve document and
    PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)the_event;
    PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.GetDocument();
    PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
    Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.GetLastContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdf);   


    ImageData image=ImageDataFactory.Create(imagePath);

    pdfCanvas.AddImage(image,(pageSize.GetWidth() / 2) - (image.GetWidth()/2), (pageSize.GetTop() - 100), true);


}
```

}

Comment: you draw the image down to `(pageSize.GetTop() - 100)`. Have you arranged your document layout to have a top margin of at least 100?

Comment: Consider this: the `HandleEvent` method can also be used by people who want to add a watermark. Suppose that iText 7 pushed all content so that it doesn't overlap with the watermark. That would be a bug, wouldn't it? iText 7 leaves all decisions done in `HandleEvent` up to the developer. If you want text to overlap with content added in `HandleEvent`, fine! If you don't want text to overlap, **do the Math and adjust the margins!**